# Move node along a path segment

Tags: inkscape

Is there an easy way to move a node of a path along a straight line that contains a straight path segment? I mean, say, I have a triangle as below. I would like to move the node denoted by "A", along the line that contains segment "AB". Is this doable?[image]

Answer (score 5):

Hold down Ctrl+Alt and move the node.

https://inkscape.org/doc/keys.html#idm1882